# Need to create a dictionary from multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary using below code:

```
def func(inp):
    return (dict(zip(inp.keys(), values)) for values in product(*inp.values()))
    
x ={'Key1': ['111', '42343'], 'key2': ['TEST', 'TESTTT123'], 'Key3': ['Cell Phone', 'e-Mail'], 'Key5': ['32142341', 'test@email.com']}
   
func(x)
```

But It gave me a cartesian product

```
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
```

However output req is:

```
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
```

any help how to avoid cartesian product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the length of the lists using `range` and use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to construct the individual dicts, selecting the `i`th element of the list each time:

```
def func(inp):
    return ({k: v[i] for k, v in inp.items()} for i in range(len(list(inp.values())[0])))
    
x = {'Key1': ['111', '42343'], 'key2': ['TEST', 'TESTTT123'], 'Key3': ['Cell Phone', 'e-Mail'], 'Key4': ['32142341', 'test@email.com']}
   
res = func(x)

for r in res:
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
{'Key1': '111', 'Key2': 'TEST', 'Key3': 'Cell Phone', 'Key4': '32142341'}
{'Key1': '42343', 'Key2': 'TESTTT123', 'Key3': 'e-Mail', 'Key4': 'test@email.com'}
```

This uses the length of the list of the first key/value pair, and assumes all the lists are of the equal length.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is pretty close but unnecessarily calls the cartesian product function. You can instead zip directly the values of the input dict so that you can iterate through them to create sub-dicts by zipping them with the keys of the input dict:

```
def func(inp):
    return (dict(zip(inp, values)) for values in zip(*inp.values()))
```